# AWS EB blocks some URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have this `CURL` command:

```
curl POST 'https://www.XXXX.com/sendsms.php' ....
```

(It's an SMS provider)
This command is working just fine on local (my computer) and I go response when using it.

When I SSH on the EB server and use the above curl, it takes like infinite time to return and no response back!

To make sure, I create another `micro server` on EC2 without EB and use CURL, suddenly I got a response!

I do not what is the problem! everything in the app is working except this service!

I'm using `AWS EB PHP 8.1 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.4.0`

my security groups on the EB server:

[image]

[image]

Comment: EB does not block any urls. It must be your  SMS provider blocking some AWS ip addresses. Its quite common for external services to put AWS ip addresses on their deny lists to protect from scraping and dos attacks.

Comment: @Marcin But the SMS provider works on the EC2 server that I created! it does not work only on EB servers!

Comment: can you curl any other website from your EB, or nothing works?

Comment: @Marcin Yeah I can curl, just this service does not work!

Comment: @Marcin I checked the SMS support and they said our service is working just fine on any server around the world and we do not block any IP or server or provider!

Comment: Maybe try re-deploying to new EB instance?

Comment: @Marcin I just re-deploying to a new EB instance, without my code & ssh, and use the curl and I got the response! I suspect my Nginx config that might cause the problem! could you pls check it here and if you see anything wrong or cause the problem of course I will be thankful https://gist.github.com/RabieAli95/029713b9422a549299f9ee9fe6f24c8b

Comment: You can make new question for the nginx setup.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments.

**Redeploying** the code in new EB environment fixed the issue. It is unknown why the `curl` did not work in the original environment.

Comment: Thanks, I just solve the problem, my Nginx config was the cuz of the problem. thank you so much again.

Comment: @rAAA No problem. Glad it worked out:-)